# The css file does not change the tables in html file

Tags: css

This is a css text, I want to give all the tables in html pages a border with width 1px. But the html files are not reading this why? I can't see any borders in html files!!!!

```
<!-- <style type="text/css"> -->
body{background-color:pink;
}
input{background-color:green;
font-color=blue;
}


table.center {
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    border-width:10px solid;

  }
.testext{color:gray};
<!-- </style> -->
```

Comment: Probably supplying more information would be helpful. Are you certain that the HTML file is correctly loading this css file at all?

Answer (score 4):

Well you have two issues:

1) The property is not `font-color` its `color` and you have an `=` instead of a `:` between the property and its value which will cause that rule to be ignored

2) You should instead use the `border` shorthand, as you're specifying two different properties using the `border-width` property which obviously only accepts a *single* `<length>` value, instead change to:

```
border: 10px solid black;
```

To gain a better understanding of CSS syntax, read the [syntax module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/)

Comment: +1 for so complete answer. For more details, user2326844, if you don't want to use shorthand properties you could set `border-style:solid`, `border-width:10px;`and `border-color:black`;.

Comment: Omitting the color from the border shorthand is perfectly valid.  Setting `color: red; border: 10px solid` is equivalent to `color: red; border: 10px solid red`.  If a color isn't provided when setting a border, it is inherited from the element's color.

Comment: @cimmanon: Thanks for pointing that out, I wasn't aware - edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
table.center {
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    border-width:10px solid;

  }
```

to

```
table {
    border: solid 10px #000;

  }
table.center {
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
  }
```

Assuming you'd done the border correctly, `table.center` would only apply to tables with the class name 'center'

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the border styles. 'solid' is not a valid value of border-width. E.g.
To produce a 10px width border:

```
table.center {
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    border-width:10px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

or combine like this:

```
table.center {
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    border: 10px solid;
}
```